# Unable to migrate database using postactivate hooks on django and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am new to website creation and am looking to create a website using django and mysql. I have been following the following tutorial: http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/install-and-configure-posgresql-for-django (note: I have been following the tutorial from the start, not just from that point). My problem comes near the bottom of that page when I try to migrate the database using `python3 manage.py migrate`. This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 199, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 171, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
>   line 176, in get_new_connection
>       connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 164, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role
>   "‘sohaib_taskbuster’" does not exist
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 359, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 294, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 345, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
>   line 83, in handle
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)   File
>   "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
>   line 20, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 52, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
>   line 203, in build_graph
>       self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
>   line 65, in applied_migrations
>       self.ensure_schema()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
>   line 52, in ensure_schema
>       if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
>   File
>   "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 231, in cursor
>       cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 204, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 199, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
>   line 94, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 199, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
>   line 171, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
>   line 176, in get_new_connection
>       connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)   File "/Users/sohaiba/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 164, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role
>   "‘sohaib_taskbuster’" does not exist

(Note the single quotes inside the double quotes in the role, username should be just sohaib_taskbuster) Now, in my settings I've set:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_env_variable('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST':'',
        'PORT':'',
    }
}
```

where get_env_variable is:

```
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

That is, it should be using the postactivate hook to pull the relevant information for the databse. This is what my postactivate hook looks like:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="taskbuster.settings.development"
export DATABASE_NAME=‘taskbuster_db’
export DATABASE_USER=‘sohaib_taskbuster’
export DATABASE_PASSWORD=‘********’
```

Using this method throws the above error, but if I use the following in my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'taskbuster_db',
        'USER': 'sohaib_taskbuster',
        'PASSWORD': '**********',
        'HOST':'',
        'PORT':'',
    }
}
```

Then the migration works fine. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas on how to fix this? (If it makes any difference, I am using postgresql)

Comment: Check the single quotes on the `DATABASE_USER` variable, they look a big different from the usual ones in the second database configuration. Try to put the correct quotes

Comment: I'm certain they're the correct quotation marks. I think the only reason they look different is because of different fonts. The postactive hooks were written and copied from TextEdit whereas the other code was copied from Atom

Comment: try removing it and adding the quotation marks from your keyboard

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work. Gives the same problem every time